# How do I change parent page url based on if url of iframe is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, surveymonkey

I have a survey monkey survey, and after I make my selections and click submit I notice that the page url changes. I know that because of same origin policy my original idea to [use jQuery to figure out if a submit occurred](http://jsfiddle.net/Omacnificent/hyfc4hte/) in the iframe will not work. JSFiddle code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var title = 'Thank you for completing our survey!';
    if($('#surveyMonkeyInfo').contents().find("div.embed_title").val() == title){
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
})
```

Then I thought, what if instead I used jQuery to see whether or not the url in the iframe is changed, although I do not get an error in which the underlying cause is SOP related, it simply does not work, nothing happens at all when the url of the iframe changes.

```
surveyMonkeyInfo.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Many apologies for the code smells if there are too many, but how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is the only one in your page. 
You can check the current URL with:

```
window.frames[0].location.href;
```

But the easy way to see if the iframe loads another url, this should work:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" onLoad="alert('Test');"></iframe>
```

The onLoad would trigger for each url change.

EDIT:

You better test with your own examples, since I cannot give you a working example on fiddle because of the cross-origin problem. If the iframe is in the same domain, you should be able to jQuery the Dom with this:

```
   window.frames[0].$('#surveyMonkeyInfo').contents().find("div.embed_title").val() == 'Thank you for completing our survey!'
```

Comment: I tried this but it changes the location on first load....I want to change the location only on second load is this not possible?

Comment: If the iframe is in the same origin, you could just test the DOM or url location.